# How to pass data from Child to Parent, if Child component dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular, events, components

http://plnkr.co/edit/AcQM5h

I've created a plunker. The structure: I have an app.ts and than a buttons.component. When I click on buttons.component I am to pass the data to app.ts and from app.ts to cats-component where I use the data.
So I am basically able to go up to the parent one level and than down other file path.

I am stuck as I am not able to pass the data from cats-component to app.ts as cats-component is generated on the fly.

This is cats component:

```
import {Component, Injector, View, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
    <div>This is the Child Component Hello world</div>
    {{colordata}}

    <input value="send me now" #catsinput />
    <button (click)="getdata(catsinput.value)">Give to parent</button>

  `,
   outputs: ['passdatatoParent']
})
export default class catsComponent {
  colordata = 0;
  passdatatoParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  getdata(value){
    this.passdatatoParent.emit(value);
    console.log('get cats data', value)
  }

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.colordata = this.injector.get('colordata');


  }
}
```

This is the parent:

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import catsComponent from './cats-component';
import dogsComponent from './dogs-component';
import DynamicComponent from './dynamic-component';
import DynamicComponent from './dynamic-component';
import {ButtonsComponent} from './buttons.component';
import {componentList} from './components-list';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>

      <buttons (passdata)="getthis($event)" ></buttons>

      <button (click)="loadDogs()">Load Dogs</button>
      <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData" (passdatatoParent)="getChildEvent($event)"></dynamic-component>
      <!--<dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData" ></dynamic-component>-->
    </div>
  `,
})



export class AppComponent {
  componentData = null;
  components:any = componentList;
  showvalue: string;

  getthis(evt){
    console.log(this.components)
    console.log('here it is' , evt);
    this.showvalue = evt;

    this.componentData = {
      component: catsComponent,
      inputs: {
        colordata: evt
      }
    };

  }
  getChildEvent(evt){
    console.log('got this from the child', evt) // NOT ABLE TO RECIEVE DATA
  }


 constructor(){

  }


  loadDogs(){
    this.componentData = {
      component: dogsComponent,
      inputs: {
        showNum: 2
      }
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, catsComponent, dogsComponent, DynamicComponent, ButtonsComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because event from `EventEmitter` doesn't bubble you can use custom DOM event to achieve it:

**cats.component.ts**

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

getdata(value){
  this.elRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('passdatatoParent', { bubbles: true, detail: value }));
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
getChildEvent(evt){
  console.log('got this from the child', evt.detail);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLQxgq?p=preview)**

2) Otherwise you have to create `@Output` event inside `DynamicComponent` and subscribe to event from dynamic component

**dynamic.component.ts**

```
passdatatoParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

subscription: any;
...
if(this.subscription) {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
if(component.instance.passdatatoParent) {
  this.subscription = component.instance.passdatatoParent
      .subscribe(x => this.passdatatoParent.emit(x))
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/agRY3i?p=preview)**

3) Another solution would be passing callback function as input

**app.component.ts**

```
this.componentData = {
  component: catsComponent,
  inputs: {
    colordata: evt,
    passdatatoParent: (val) => {
      console.log(val);
    }
  }
};
```

**cats.component.ts**

```
getdata(value){
  this.injector.get('passdatatoParent')(value);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JqwIa1?p=preview)**

Comment: based on  your first results I checked what is : ElementRef to see what func and got 'Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks.' on angular site:
https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html
Any ideas? is really a risk?

Comment: If you aren't going to use webworker or server rendering then i don't see any problem here

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declare-directives-and-components

Comment: on 2 version, I don't seem to work as in app.ts on line 46 it should log it out but in the log don't seem see anything

Comment: I don't see your result. Any plunker?

Comment: i am talking about ur plunkers , that u got in option 2 http://plnkr.co/edit/agRY3i?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FOiBOKSSy6SSFrOHblI0?p=preview
Ok,gone with option 1 but stuck on trying to load data into the dynamic component that has been intialised already.
On the plunker if you click "load cats” button you will see that there is other componet that loads next to it. I'm now trying to pass the extra data from the input field also in the same cats component. 
And if I change in cats component input field value to pass the new changed value back to the "extra data” input value field. Can’t figure out how to get the extra data passed back and forward.